# igCombo Resets the text value after loading new dataSource

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui, igcombo

I am using Infragistics igCombo in my implementation. When the user inputs 3 letters, I fetch the data and load in the dropdown list by calling the dataSource method. After loading the data in the igCombo dropdown, the already input text by user is deleted automatically and the combobox shows empty string

Comment: Can you show your igCombo configuration? And the code where you're loading the new dataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `allowCustomValue: true` to the combo, then the input text should remain after a rebind.